# Easiest way to return list<T> without first element

Tags: .net, linq, list

Somehow I don´t get this at the moment as I want.

I get data from database via NHibernate.

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Price));
criteria.AddOrder(new NHibernate.Expression.Order("ValidFrom", false));
List<Price> prices = criteria.List().Cast<Price>().ToList();
```

Now I want to return the list without the first element (the newest price). I got something working, but what would be the easiest way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be writing `criteria.List().Cast<Price>().Skip(1).ToList();`

Comment: Agree, `Skip(1)` is the way to go

Comment: I would probably do `Skip(1)` before the `Cast`, removes a little bit of overhead.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg, you can't because most Linq methods (including Skip) only work on the generic IEnumerable interface, and criteria.List a non-generic IList

Comment: Ah! Didn't know that `List()` returned a non-generic.